# How to set route in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have created simple functionality that allows to change allows to change language on page just by pushing language right after URL - `i18n-next`. Here is how it looks like:

```
  const [languages, ] = React.useState([{
    language: 'Polish',
    prefix: 'pl'
  }, {
    language: 'Russian',
    prefix: 'ru'
  }, {
    language: 'English',
    prefix: 'en'
  }]);

  const changeLanguage = async (language: string) => {
    for (const lang of languages) {
      if (lang.language === language) {
        setPickedLanguage(lang.flag);
        await router.push(lang.prefix);
      }
    }
  };
```

The problem is, when user changes language on front-end in url you may have something like this - `/pl/en` - if you change language twice or more. What I want to do is to set only once this language prefix, so it will be only `/en`, `/pl` and `/ru` - and no those double routes.

I can't find anything in `next` docs, so how can I fix it?

Comment: Could it be a problem that the prefix doesn't start with `/` ? If it's not that then we'd need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer, what you need to do, is instead of `router` object use `Link`, so on front it would look like this:

[Source](https://daily.dev/blog/internationalization-i18n-in-nextjs#sub-path-routing)

```
const ChangeLanguage = ({ defaultLanguage }: ChangeLanguageProps) => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();

  const [showLanguages, setShowLanguages] = React.useState(false);
  const [pickedLanguage, setPickedLanguage] = React.useState('');
  const [languages, ] = React.useState([{
    language: 'Polish',
    flag: '',
    prefix: 'pl'
  }, {
    language: 'Russian',
    flag: '',
    prefix: 'ru'
  }, {
    language: 'English',
    flag: '',
    prefix: 'en'
  }]);

  const changeLanguage = async (language: string) => {
    for (const lang of languages) {
      if (lang.language === language) {
        setPickedLanguage(lang.flag);
        setShowLanguages(false);
      }
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    switch (defaultLanguage) {
      case 'en':
        setPickedLanguage('');
        break;
      case 'ru':
        setPickedLanguage('');
        break;
      case 'pl':
        setPickedLanguage('');
        break;
      default:
        setPickedLanguage('');
        break;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PickedLanguage
        onClick={() => setShowLanguages(!showLanguages)}
      >{pickedLanguage}</PickedLanguage>
      <ChangeLanguageContainer>
        {showLanguages ? (
          <LanguagesList>
            {languages.map(item => (
              <Link
                key={item.language}
                href={asPath}
                locale={item.prefix}
              >
                <LanguageItem>
                  {item.prefix}
                </LanguageItem>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </LanguagesList>
        ):  null}
      </ChangeLanguageContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```